# Using igraph/R to get the top 10 shortest path

Tags: r, igraph, shortest-path

I'm using the igraph package in R and I'm looking for a way to subgraph the max top 10 shortest path from a previous graph.

Anyone have some suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Do you have some code you're looking for help on?

Comment: No, I'm sorry. I just setting the shortest path as a attribute E(g)$ShP, and ordered it using `E(g)$ShP[order(E(g)$ShP)]`, but i dont know how to get the top 10.

Comment: What do you mean by extract the top ten shortest path ? You want 10 new graphs having just the nodes and the edges on the 10 shortest paths ?

Comment: Kinda. I want only one graph at the end that show the union of the nodes and edges on the 10 shortest path. Do you think that this is possible?

Comment: Actually, I don't know if there's a function that gives you all the paths between two vertices (ranked by length) in igraph... I think there are only functions returning the shortest paths (even all of them, but only if they're of the same minimum length)

Answer (score 0):

First create some graph:

```
set.seed(1)
require(igraph)
g <- erdos.renyi.game(100,.2)
```

Then extract all shortest paths and calculate their length:

```
plist <- do.call(c,
            lapply(V(g), function(v) get.shortest.paths(g,v,V(g), output='epath')$epath))
```

Now figure out which paths are the top ten:

```
psize <- data.frame(i = 1:length(plist), plength = sapply(plist,length))

top10 <- head(psize[order(-psize$plength),],10)
```

Now figure out which edges this involves:

```
elist <- unlist(plist[top10$i])
```

And finally, get the subgraph which contains these vertices:

```
finalg <- subgraph.edges(g, elist)
```

The before and after plots:

[image: Some initial random graph]

[image: The final subgraph with top ten shortest paths only]